# Material UI react testing custom styles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I'm struggling to come up with a sensible way of asserting that a given style will be added to a Material-UI component when a given prop is specified

```js
import makeStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/makeStyles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  myRoot: props => props.inverse && {
    border: "2px solid red",
  },
})

const MyTextInput = ({ inverse, ...otherProps }) => {
  const classes = useStyles({ inverse });
  return (
    <TextField
      label="Standard secondary"
      color="secondary"
      classes={{
        root: classes.myRoot,
      }}
    />
  );
}


// with inverse
<MyTextInput
  label="Standard secondary"
  color="secondary"
  inverse={true}
/>

// without inverse prop
<MyTextInput
  label="Standard secondary"
  color="secondary"
/>
```

Is there a sensible way to test that the correct class has been applied?

I notice that when I render the component multiple times, the className + a number will be added to all instances e.g. `makeStyles-myRoot-*`.

Is there way of confirming that the correct style has been applied?

I'm using `react-testing-library` if that helps.

Comment: I'm reading how Material UI test `useStyles` / `makeStyles` and the approach I will probably follow is based on how they test their components.

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/9bd4277ecd660ebe2fd4cb08960f58e98ddb6d43/packages/material-ui-styles/src/makeStyles/makeStyles.test.js#L315